# Unable to open WP8 emulator within Visual Studio (opening from Hyper-V manager works)

Tags: windows, internet, phone, emulator

Now this problem is (so it seems) directly connected with this issue:
[No Internet access on Windows Phone 8 emulator (despite working connection in Windows 8)](https://superuser.com/questions/504189/no-internet-access-on-wp8-emulator-despite-working-connection-in-win8)

I will explain in a minute, as to how.

I have a problem running emulator within Visual Studio. When I try to deply my application(to which stage I cannot arive, cause the emulator cannot load fully to begin with) the emulator shows and the message is displayed that the emulator is being started, but nothing happens for about 5 minutes, and afterwards I get this message:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/187008

"The Windows Phone Emulator wasn't able to connect to the Windows Phone operating system"

Strangely enough the emulator runs without any problem(and in matter of 15-30 seconds) if I try to start it within the Hyper-V manager.

Now let me go back to why this issue is connected to the one I mentioned earlier. When I share my main connection with the Emulator Virtual Switch I get the error I described above. However if I turn off sharing, the emulator starts (but without the internet, which makes it useless for me) normaly.

If anybody had the same case as me all the way to sharing internet to the emulator without the external router, and was able to fix this issue I would greatly appriciate any help.

As a sidenote I want to say that I'm "amazed" at how poor job Microsoft did on the WP8 emulator taking into account their strict WP7 certification process. I won't even start on Win8 as a whole, but that's like I've said, is just a sidenote.

Lucas

Comment: Hi Lucas, could you figure it out? I have exactly the same problem as you do. As soon as I turn on sharing, internet works, but Visual Studio cannot connect to the emulator anymore.

Comment: Yep, same issue here too. Starting the emulator from Hyper-v Manager works, but through Visual Studio it doesn't. Disabling the Internet Sharing fixes this issue and the emulator can start, but then we lose the internet connection.